# How can I ignore latex error while compiling?

Tags: errors, tex-core, compiling

When a tex file is compiled, everytime an error is detected, compilation stops and user action (usually hitting return key) is expected through console by user. I would like to ask, how is it possible to avoid this. I would like it not to stop on detected errors and finish with compilation of the tex file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What I would advise you is to use this;

```
latex -interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error filename.tex
```

Specifying `-interaction nonstopmode` is equivalent to using `\nonstopmode` in your document.

The `-halt-on-error` option instructs the program to return a non-zero error code when an error is found. This is useful when you are e.g. calling latex from a script or from the [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) utility. Using `make` or an equivalent program like e.g. [`scons`](http://www.scons.org/) is highly recommended for larger documents that have an index or use citations. Because in those cases you will not only have to call LaTeX but also the programs to generate an index and bibliography.

The `-file-line-error` option is makes it easier to locate errors in your source files, especially when you use `\include` to e.g. split up a long document into parts (like splitting a book into chapters and putting each chapter in a separate TeX file.

Here is a Makefile fragment that I use for big LaTeX documents;

```
$(DOCPDF): $(SUBDIR) $(TEXSRC) lbref.bib .git/index
        sh tools/vc -m
        python tools/mkhistory.py hist.tex
        pdflatex --interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error $*.tex # >/dev/null
        makeindex -c -s myindex.ist $*.idx #2>/dev/null
        bibtex $* #>/dev/null
        pdflatex --interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error $*.tex #>/dev/null
        makeindex -c -s myindex.ist $*.idx #2>/dev/null
        pdflatex  --interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error $*.tex #>/dev/null
        rm -f $*.lo* *.aux $*.ilg $*.ind $*.toc $*.bbl $*.blg $*.out *.asc
```

The first line specifies that the commands have to be carried out when either the tex source document (the `TEXSRC` variable), the bibliography database (`lbref.bib`) or the revision control status (`.git/index`) has changed. The first two commands add the revision number to the document and add a list of changes. After that it calls `pdflatex` a couple of times interspersed with calls to `makeindex` and `bibtex`. Several calls to LaTeX are generally necessary to resolve and stabilize all references when using `makeindex`.

**Edit**: I've switched to using `latexmk` because it will automatically take care of resolving cross-references,  bibliographies and such.

So I've modified my Makefile:

```
SUBDIR= figuren lam calc grafieken
OUTDIR= uitvoer
DOCPDF = $(DOCSRC:.tex=.pdf)

# This is the first target in the Makefile.
all:  $(DOCPDF)

PDFLATEX= xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error
$(DOCPDF): $(SUBDIR) $(TEXSRC) lbref.bib .git/index
        -latexmk -bibtex -recorder -outdir=$(OUTDIR) -auxdir=$(OUTDIR) -pdflatex="$(PDFLATEX)" -pdf $(DOCSRC) 2>&1|grep -C12 '^l\.'
        mv  $(OUTDIR)/$(DOCPDF) .

${SUBDIR}::
        cd ${.TARGET}; make ${.TARGETS}
```

I've switched to `xelatex` for its simpler font handling.
All the output files are now put in a subfirectory as to not clutter the main directory and for easier cleaning. Only the resulting PDF file is moved to the main directory after it has been created.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Ronald, thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode foo.tex
```