# How can I ignore pdflatex missing package errors while compiling (pdflatex)?

Tags: errors, compiling

My question is related to [How can I ignore latex error while compiling?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140845/).
I have a document (for testing purposes) which uses `mathbx` package. Unfortunately my Miktex distribution is old (but I am happy with it). When compiling some file (for testing purposes) I get the error of missing this package. I tried to use the suggestion of the above question using `pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -halt-on-error -file-line-error filename.tex` but it doesn't work. It says

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mathabx.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
 :12: Emergency stop
No pages of output.
Transcript written on filename.log.
```

How can I ignore all pdflatex missing package errors while compling?

Comment: You shouldn't ignore these errors: the document might contain commands that are specific to the packages you don't have.

Comment: @egreg You are right, in general I should not ignore such errors. But this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: You could create an empty file `mathabx.sty` in the document folder.

Comment: Well, update your distribution or drop the missing package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer as I said, this is just for compiling some files for experimental-testing purposes. I am looking for a solution which just ignore such errors. The question also arises for some nonstandard packages which are not part of the official distribution thus updating distribution doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\IfFileExists` can be used to only load the package if the package file exits:

```
\IfFileExists{mathabx.sty}{\usepackage{mathabx}}{%
  % place for definitions to simulate the missing package, example:
  \providecommand*{\widecheck}{\check}%
}
```

If the package does not exist, macros defined by the package can be provided in the third argument of `\IfFileExists` or `\providecommand` can be used for some dummy definitions to prevent/reduce further errors because of missing macro definitions.

Comment: Thanks, just a question, the document uses `\widecheck` (part of `mathbx`). With your solution, how can I tell LaTeX to use the ordinary `\check` instead of `\widecheck` when `mathbx` is missing?