# How can I make LaTex typeset a PDF regardless of an error?

Tags: errors, pdf

When LaTex encounters an error in the .tex window (source) it reports the error in the console when I hit 'typeset' but does NOT produce a PDF. This is particularly distressing when I'm 40 pages into a report and can't figure out what the source of the error is. All I get is the error message and the source window. Any previous version of the compiled PDF is no longer available. I want the PDF to be produced regardless of any errors, so that I have a legible document if this happens minutes from a submission deadline. I'm using TeXShop on a mac, should I perhaps be using something else? 
Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ignore latex error while compiling?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140845/how-can-i-ignore-latex-error-while-compiling)

Comment: Rather than trying to force a compilation of an errored document source, a common approach to resolving the issue is to place `\end{document}` earlier in  the document where compilation is successful.  Then, by successively moving this `\end{document}` closer and closer to the end of the document until the compilation refails, the source of the problem can be ascertained to the block of code over which the most recent move took place. (One most only be careful *not* to move `\end{document}` inside of a "group")

Comment: @knut It's not a duplicate IMHO. The duplicate is about an interaction free compile run (batch mode), but the question also wants to have a PDF file as result.

Comment: Yes that's right, I am not prompted to interact when an error occurs, the issue is that no PDF is produced when strange errors occur that I may be unable to find the source of in a 40 or 80 page report.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible. Whether TeX can continue, heavily depends on the kind of error. `\batchmode` or `\nonstopmode` can be used to let TeX continue until the TeX job is finished or aborted. But this does not say anything, whether the PDF file is generated. When an error occurs, TeX cannot clairvoyance. Sometimes the error is fatal with immediate abortion. Sometimes TeX's error recovery lets continue the job at least, but with crumbled output maybe.

Also there can be documents, which are free of any errors or warnings, but do not generate any pages, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Also some dubious code can sometimes change the output mode to DVI.